# Install custom JAX-RS JSON de-/serialization in Wildfly

Tags: java, module, jax-rs, wildfly

Suppose we have the situation of an `.ear` application containing multiple `.war` and `.jar` where we control the JSON de-/serialization of our objects in our REST endpoints through custom `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` packaged inside of one specific `.jar` deployed as a lib with our `.ear`.

Now, as we are about to expand the number of deployments all using the aforementioned custom de-/serialization we search for a way to reduce the artifact size and I came up with basically three possibilities where only two work and one seems too verbose to be a real solution:

- Deploy the `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`-artifact with each `.ear` refering to it (Drawback: multiple `.ear`-artifacts containing the *same* `.jar` library).
- Install the  `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`-artifact as a global Wildfly module and add a dependency through the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` (Drawback: The `.ear`-artifact can be deployed but the de-/serialization did not work as expected as a Wildfly module is not part of the classpath of a deployed `.ear`-application and the `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` are not registered automatically on deployment).
- Install the  `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`-artifact as a "normal" Wildfly module and reference the custom `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` in the `getClasses` method of the REST configuration class which extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` (Drawback: We would have to list every `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` and REST endpoint explicitely instead of the automated discovery used at the moment).

Is there a fourth possibility to achieve this task or are there any tweaks on the three possibilities above? I did not manage to find any solution to this (I thought) rather basic task of installing a "global" custom `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` in Wildfly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was as easy as unmanageable to find properly:

Either:

1. The `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`-artifact is being extended by a file named `javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` placed in `/META-INF/services` where all classes being annotated with `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` are listed with their fully qualified class names.
2. The `.ear`-artifact `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is extended by two dependencies:

   1. `<module name="<module-name>" slot="main" />` for the `<deployment>`-element.
   2. `<module name="<module-name>" slot="main" services="import" />` for the `.war`-artifacts `<sub-deployment>`-element(s) who (implicitely) use classes of the `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`-artifact.

Or:

1. Leave the `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`-artifact as it was before.
2. The `.ear`-artifact `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` is extended by two dependencies:

   1. `<module name="<module-name>" slot="main" annotations="true" />` for the `<deployment>`-element.
   2. `<module name="<module-name>" slot="main" />` for the `.war`-artifacts `<sub-deployment>`-element(s) who (implicitely) use classes of the `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`-artifact.

Comment: slot="main" is not needed, but service="import" is the main thing you needed.